# Dificuldade em criar uma query em mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho esta tabela:

TipoTarefa:

```
Id, Descricao
17, Depilação Buço
18, Depilação Pernas
19, Depilação Orelhas
20, Depilação Barba
21, Cortar Unhas Pés
22, Cortar Unhas Mãos
28, Esvaziar Saco Urina
29, Hidratação
36, Medicação
37, Deitar Utente
47, Levar Roupa para Lavandaria
48, Arrumar Lixo
73, Encaminhamento de Utente para Deitar (Pós Almoço)
77, Fazer Cama
```

Depois tenho a tabela dos Utentes:

```
codigo, nome,       quarto, cama
2,      Pedro,        15,    1
6,      Paulo Moura,  12,    2
3,      Bruno,        12,    1
4,      ANTONIO,      21,    1
```

Agora tenho a tabela onde registo as tarefas, onde já fiz a query que retorna as tarefas realizadas no dia atual:

```
SELECT raddb.Tarefa.codigo, Colaborador, FimTarefa, Ala, nome, raddb.TipoTarefa.Id, Descricao

FROM raddb.Tarefa LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa ON raddb.TipoTarefa.Id = raddb.Tarefa.tarefa  

LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.quartos ON raddb.quartos.Codigo = raddb.Tarefa.codigo

LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.Utente ON raddb.Utente.quarto = raddb.quartos.Quarto AND raddb.Utente.Cama = raddb.quartos.Cama

WHERE raddb.TipoTarefa.Id IN ('17','18','19','20','21','22','28','29','36','37','47','48','73','77') AND DATE(FimTarefa) = DATE(NOW())
```

Que retorna isto:

```
codigo, Colaborador, FimTarefa, Ala, nome, Id, Descricao
150001, 28, 2019-07-29 11:30:08, ALA A, Pedro, 28, Esvaziar Saco Urina
110001, 33, 2019-07-29 16:10:27, ALA A, Pedro, 36, Medicação
110001, 33, 2019-07-29 17:16:27, ALA A, Pedro, 21, Cortar Unhas Pés
```

Nesta última `query` retorna só três tarefas realizadas ao Pedro durante o dia de hoje, a tarefa 28,36 e 21.Então o que pretendo é que em vez de retornar as tarefas realizadas no dia de hoje, me retornasse as tarefas que não foram realizadas no dia de hoje, que neste caso eram as tarefas 17,18,19,20,22,29,37,47,48,73,77.

Dados da coluna tarefa e quarto:

Tabela Quarto:

```
Id, Codigo, Quarto, Cama, Ala
1,  010001,   1,      1, ALA A
2,  020101,   2,      1, ALA A
3,  020201,   2,      2, ALA A
4,  030001,   3,      1, ALA A
5,  040101,   4,      1, ALA A
6,  040201,   4,      2, ALA A
7,  050001,   5,      1, ALA A
8,  060101,   6,      1, ALA A
9,  060201,   6,      2, ALA A
10, 070001,   7,      1, ALA A
```

e esta é a tabela tarefa:

```
Id, codigo, IniciarTarefa, tarefa, FimTarefa, Colaborador, check, Acompnhante, Observacao, Notas, Mes, Ano, Turno
127, 110001, 2019-07-29 16:10:12, 36, 2019-07-29 16:10:27, 33, , , , Teste, 06, 2019, T
135, 110001, 2019-07-29 17:16:21, 21, 2019-07-29 17:16:27, 33, , , , , 06, 2019, T
240, 150001, 2019-07-29 11:30:02, 28, 2019-07-29 11:30:08, 28, , , , , 07, 2019, M
```

Comment: Tentou `right join` ?     `raddb.Tarefa RIGHT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa`

Comment: @Edvaldo Lucena retorna o mesmo resultado do `left outer join`

Comment: Pode postar amostra de dados das colunas `Tarefa` e  `quartos` ... quero simular aqui a consulta.

Comment: @Edvaldo Lucena atualizei a pergunta com os dados da tabela tarefa e da tabela quartos que contêm a coluna tarefa e a coluna quarto.

Comment: na tabela Utente ficou faltando vc colocar a coluna quarto, pode atualizar ?

Comment: @Edvaldo Lucena, já atualizei a tabela utente com a coluna quarto e cama

Comment: blz, vou fazer alguns testes e te retorno ...

Comment: Consegue fazer um [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) com a sua estrutura, dados e query atual?

Comment: @Sorack Fiz aqui o que pediu [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab8388/4) e aqui retorna as tarefas que foram realizadas e pretendo é retornar as tarefas que não foram realizadas naquele dia, claro as outras colunas vão aparecer vazias

Comment: O que não ficou claro é o que você quer retornar. Você quer retornar uma tarefa que não foi feita por quarto? Por colaborador? Demonstre os resultados que deseja receber

Comment: @Sorack faltou isso, mas pretendo retornar por quarto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` para verificar na tabela `tarefa` qual `TipoTarefa` não tem nenhum registro (utilizando o `CROSS JOIN` com a tabela `quarto` para realizar o vínculo de todos os `TipoTarefa` com todos os `quarto`):

```
SELECT tt.descricao,
       q.ala,
       q.quarto,
       q.cama
  FROM tipotarefa tt
 CROSS JOIN quartos q
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tarefa t
                   WHERE t.tarefa = tt.id
                     AND t.codigo = q.codigo
                     AND DATE(t.fimtarefa) = '2019-07-29')
 ORDER BY q.ala,
          q.quarto,
          q.cama,
          tt.descricao
```

---

**Resultando em:**

```
| descricao           | ala   | quarto | cama |
| ------------------- | ----- | ------ | ---- |
| Esvaziar Saco Urina | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação1          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação10         | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação11         | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação2          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação3          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação4          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação5          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação6          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação7          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação8          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Medicação9          | ALA A | 11     | 1    |
| Cortar Unhas Pés    | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Esvaziar Saco Urina | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação           | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação1          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação10         | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação11         | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação2          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação3          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação4          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação5          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação6          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação7          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação8          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Medicação9          | ALA A | 12     | 2    |
| Cortar Unhas Pés    | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação           | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação1          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação10         | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação11         | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação2          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação3          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação4          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação5          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação6          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação7          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação8          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Medicação9          | ALA A | 15     | 1    |
| Cortar Unhas Pés    | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Esvaziar Saco Urina | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação           | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação1          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação10         | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação11         | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação2          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação3          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação4          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação5          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação6          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação7          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação8          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
| Medicação9          | ALA B | 21     | 1    |
```

---

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a `subquery` returns any rows at all, `EXISTS subquery` is `TRUE`, and `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `FALSE`

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a `subquery` retornar qualquer linha, `EXISTS` será `VERDADEIRO`, e `NOT EXISTS` será `FALSO`